# VBA Save a Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, save

There is my code where I try to Save a Workbook in a specific place:

```
Private Sub zouzou()

    Nom = Cherche("Z:\3_BASE\WORK\BD\01 - PRODUCTION\" & SE & "\" & Batch & "\" & TMD & "\01 - ANALYSE IMPACT\")
    
    FDP = "Z:\3_BASE\WORK\BD\01 - PRODUCTION\" & SE & "\" & Batch & "\" & TMD & "\01 - ANALYSE IMPACT\" & Nom
    
    Enregistrement FDP, Nom

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Enregistrement(Chemin, Nom)
    
    DossierConcat = "Z:\3_BASE\WORK\BD\01 - PRODUCTION" & SE & "\" & Batch & "\" & TMD & "\99 - AS DATA VERIFICATION\Input\"
   
    Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(Chemin)
    
    WB1.SaveAs Filename:=DossierConcat & Nom
    
    Workbooks(Chemin).Close False
    
End Sub
```

My code work until the line  `WB1.SaveAs Filename:=DossierConcat & Nom`

Nom = `ZOZOT.xlsx`
And I get error message:

> "Runtime Error '1004': Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed"

I don't understand why I got this message, any ideas?

Comment: When using `SaveAs` you must add the filename and filetype. It looks like your variable Nom should end in something like `\folder\filename.xlsx`. Try to debug it with F8 and see the exact value of your variable Nom in the line `WB1.SaveAs Filename:=DossierConcat & Nom`

Comment: I already try to debug it with F8 and the exact value of my variable Nom is ```ZOZOT.xlsx```. This is why I don't understand this error.

Comment: ¿What is the value of `DossierConcat & Nom`?

Comment: Oh DossierConcat was false ```Z:\3_BASE\WORK\BD\01 - PRODUCTION3APA\BATCH18\TMD1002\99 - AS DATA VERIFICATION\Input\``` I forgot a \ in the path... Sorry and thanks you for the help !